# Ruin Probability Question

Tags: poisson-process

In an insurance company the number of claims are modelled as a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. Assume that the size of all claims is a fixed amount $\alpha>0$, the initial surplus is denoted by $u$, with $0 < u < \alpha$. If the premium income per unit time is $1.73\lambda\alpha$, find the probability that ruin happens at the first claim.

Comment: What have you tried. It's best to submit questions with your attempted working as more people will be willing to help

Comment: Homework or problem set questions without showing any effort are not suitable for this website.